# Create a scheduler in Azure that fetches data from Azure SQL DB and post to on-premise system

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, scheduler

I have a requirement where a scheduler needs to be developed that would run once per day (preferably in .Net C# as console app), hosted on Azure. This scheduler will connect a Azure SQL DB, fetch data and post to an on-premise system. This system is some kind of application where it has REST web api available for posting data. I don't have experience in Azure and confused which service I should be using in Azure to host this scheduler and how it will connect to Azure SQL DB and then to the on-premise system via API.

Comment: Azure Functions please.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you can create that scheduler using [Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/integration/logic-apps-data-integration). You can create scheduler jobs using Azure Logic Apps [workflows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/create-single-tenant-workflows-azure-portal). Azure Logic Apps can connect to on-premises SQL Server data sources using a [data gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/hybrid/gateway-logic-apps). It is possible to interact with workflows using [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/).